# C# Collection Group by performance Optimization

Tags: c#, list, linq, collections

I have below LINQ query which is taking about a min to group by my data of around 65,000 records. Is there any way to optimize further to decrease the time.

```
var grouped = (from T1 in dataCollection.trancollection
group T1 by new { T1.Name, T1.ExternalID, T1.AccountNumber, T1.Code, T1.Location, T1.Date, T1.CurrencyCode, T1.StatusName } into g
select new
{
   Id = g.Key,
   groupedDocs = g,
   Amount = g.Sum(x => x.TranAmount),
   USDAmt = g.Sum(x => x.USDTranAmount)                                                                 
 }).ToList();
```

The data to this collection is fed through another API call. Is there any alternative approach to improve performance? And my collection type is IReadOnlyCollection<>

Thanks much for any help !

Comment: can you group by less properties, maybe just `ExternalID` ?

Comment: I'm fairly sure this will cause your ORM to make one query for the group keys, and then *one query per group* (also known as the N+1 problem), since you're asking for `groupedDocs = g`. Since you're loading all the rows anyway, it might be more performant to simply select the fields you need (going into the group) plus `TranAmount` and `USDTranAmount` and do the grouping in memory.

Comment: you need to find out which point took a lot of time. Call API or LINQ. 
So, let's get all data from API without LINQ firstly.

Comment: Hi Slai - My collection has almost 30 properties, but grouping by only 10 properties.

Comment: hiule - The time was taking only with this group by and not by API call. Because, the collection is loaded once my API call is completed

Comment: Hi Rob - Since my collection has almost 30 props, i m grouping by 10 properties and selecting the same grouped columns. I didn't get your last statement of select the fields you need + tranamounts to group in memory...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is all running in memory, we could try optimizing the two calls to `Sum` into one call to `Aggregate` but I am not sure that will be faster:

```
var grouped = (from T1 in dataCollection.trancollection
               group T1 by new { T1.Name, T1.ExternalID, T1.AccountNumber, T1.Code, T1.Location, T1.Date, T1.CurrencyCode, T1.StatusName } into g
               let sumPair = g.Aggregate(new { SumAmount = 0.0, SumUSD = 0.0 }, (sump, x) => new { SumAmount = sump.SumAmount + x.TranAmount, USDAmt = sump.USDAmount + x.USDTranAmount })
               select new {
                   Id = g.Key,
                   groupedDocs = g,
                   Amount = sumPair.SumAmount,
                   USDAmt = sumPair.SumUSD
               }).ToList();
```

Comment: Assuming this is all running in memory with only 65,000 records this should only take milliseconds.